# Take geolocation info (longitude, latitude, altitude) from a set of files in a folder using Excel VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I want to take geotag information from the properties of a set of image files in a folder that is referenced in the Excel file directly (so it can be applied to different folders). It's supposed paste the file name, longitude, latitude, and altitude for each file in a new row in the Excel worksheet.

There is an

> Error 424: Object Required.

I tried code found on Stack and elsewhere online but they didn't work the way I needed so I tried it myself using those as a reference.

```vb
Sub ExtractPhotoData()

    'Declare variables
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim SourceFolder As Object
    Dim FileItem As Object
    Dim Image As Object
    Dim RowCounter As Integer
    
    'Set up the file system object and source folder
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set SourceFolder = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 9).Value
    
    'Loop through each file in the source folder
    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
    
        'Check if the file is an image
        If InStr(1, FileItem.Type, "image") > 0 Then
        
            'Load the image
            Set Image = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")
            Image.LoadFile FileItem.Path
            
            'Extract the longitude, latitude, and altitude data
            Dim Longitude As String
            Dim Latitude As String
            Dim Altitude As String
            Longitude = Image.Properties("GPS Longitude").Value
            Latitude = Image.Properties("GPS Latitude").Value
            Altitude = Image.Properties("GPS Altitude").Value
            
            'Paste the data into the worksheet
            RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
            Cells(RowCounter, 1).Value = FileItem.Name
            Cells(RowCounter, 2).Value = Longitude
            Cells(RowCounter, 3).Value = Latitude
            Cells(RowCounter, 4).Value = Altitude
        
        End If
    
    Next FileItem

End Sub
```

Comment: What line does the code stop on? (use F8 to go through the code line-by-line to see which line is throwing the error)

Answer (score 0):

Because SourceFolder is declared as worksheet ( set SourceFolder = Work...) , it is an object that only knows about excel sheets.  It doesn't deal with files.  So we need to loop on the FSO, not the SourceFolder.  So change to FSO for the loop, but when you do that, i think it will need an initialization to specify what directory to start in.

I don't see that the FileSystemObject can do what you are wanting (list of files) so you might take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/folder-object which can return a list of files.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Your suggestion worked. I changed the Set SourceFolder to  = FSO.GetFolder(Worksheets...) but now a new error is popping up saying - Run-Time error '-2145320854 (8021006a)'. I believe it has something to do with the use of WIA although I'm unsure. I found another post on Stack with a similar issue but no solution was found.

Comment: I don't think you should pass the folder address to the FSO.GetFolder...   So try something like FSO.GetFolder("C:\users\yourname\desktop\myExcels").   That should give you a folder object back that you can then ask for a list of files.